# Updating contents inside a list of structs

Tags: c#, list, forms, struct, replace

I have a List of structs

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>()
```

and I want to find a specific student, then update it's information. To do that I have the following code inside a method

```
Student tmpStudent = new Student();
tmpStudent.fName = txtFName.Text;
studentList.Find(i => i.fName == tmpStudent.fName).fName.Replace(tmpStudent.fName, "newName");
```

but the problem us that it doesn't seem to be working. When I show the contents of the list of structs I still have the old version

```
string tmp = "";
foreach (Student s in studentList)
{
    tmp += s.fName + " " + s.lName + " " + s.Gpa.ToString() + "\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(tmp);
```

What is the correct way to achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: Mutable structs is not a good idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: Student sounds like it should be a `class`, not a `struct`; it is **incredibly** rare to create a `struct` in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Replace` does not do an "in place" replacement of a string - it *returns* a new string with the replaced text.

You need to assign the returned replaced string back to the `fName` property.

```
var foundStudent = studentList.Find(i => i.fName == tmpStudent.fName);
foundStudent.fName = foundStudent.fName.Replace(foundStudent.fName, "newName");
```

Though the second line appears to be overly verbose (you simply need to assign the new name):

```
var foundStudent = studentList.Find(i => i.fName == tmpStudent.fName);
foundStudent.fName = "newName";
```

Answer (score 2):

Whay are you using `Replace` here? Why not just assign the new value directly?

```
Student s = studentList.Find(i => i.fName == txtFName.Text);
s.fName = "newName";
```

Also, structs should be immutable value-like types. Your `Student` type should be a class.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings are immutable fName.Replace(tmpStudent.fName, "newName") returns a new string. This needs to be added to the struct,